# Laravel : How to display data using for and foreach in blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, postgresql, laravel-7

I want to display data based on the provided template table, using the for and foreach loop, but when else conditions always display an index of its own

This is my expectation :

[image: expectation img]

This is my data :

[image: data img]

And this is happening now :

[image: result img]

and this is my code :

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)

@foreach ($scheduleDetails as $item)
    @if ($i == $item->day)
        <td class="p-1">
            <input name="from[]" value="{{substr($item->from_time,0,-3)}}" id="from{{$i}}" style="width:50px;margin:auto" class="text-center" type="text" readonly>
        </td>
        <td class="p-1">
            <input name="until[]" value="{{substr($item->until_time,0,-3)}}" id="until{{$i}}" style="width:50px;margin:auto" class="text-center" type="text" readonly>
        </td>
    @else
        <td>{{$i}}</td>
    @endif
@endforeach

@endfor
```

Thanks..

Comment: If you want to format time, you can put from and until time in the dates array in your model. That would give you access to Carbon functions. OR simply use `date` function to format time. As for numbers being printed, you are printing the index if day is not found. Replace that with dash.

Comment: no, I want to eliminate the 0 & 2 index when else happens. if to display the time, for example 08:00 I can use substrings. thank you for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using `keyBy` function by making `day` column as index from the result of `$scheduleDetails`

```
@php $newScheduleDetails = $scheduleDetails->keyBy('day'); @endphp
@for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
   @if($newScheduleDetails->has($i))
       <td class="p-1">
            <input name="from[]" value="{{$newScheduleDetails->get($i)->from_time }}" id="from{{$i}}" style="width:50px;margin:auto" type="text">
        </td>
        <td class="p-1">
            <input name="until[]" value="{{$newScheduleDetails->get($i)->until_time }}" id="until{{$i}}" style="width:50px;margin:auto" type="text">
        </td>
   @else
        <td>{{$i}}</td>
        <td>{{$i}}</td>
   @endif
@endfor
```

Comment: thanks a lot, its worked. first, I got a message "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array". But i changed value="{{$newScheduleDetails->get($i)['from_time']}}" to
value="{{$newScheduleDetails->get($i)->from_time}}"